# How to force parameter be empty object in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function that creates functions.

for example

```
function createFunc<T>()
{
   return (params: T) => params /* do stuff here */;
}
```

and use it for type checking. So, for example, I can create a function with this signature

```
login = createFunc<{username:string,password:string}>();
```

Now it's checking login method inputs to be `{username:string,password:string}`

But how can I do this for an empty object?

When I pass `{}` its allow to put anything in the input, I want to check that input must be empty object **only**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript will not trigger excess property checks for `{}`. So if you want to forbid properties with extra properties you could treat this case explicitly using a conditional type:

```
function createFunc<T>():
    keyof T extends never ?
        (params: Record<string, never>) => {} :
        (params: T) => T 
function createFunc()
{
    return (params: any) => params /* do stuff here */;
}


const empty = createFunc<{  }>();
empty({
    password: "",
    username: ""
})
```

You should be careful about relying to much on excess property checks, they are only triggered when you assign an object literal directly to the parameter. This for example passes:

```
const login = createFunc<{ username: string, password: string }>();

const p = {
    password: "",
    password2: "",
    username: ""
}
login(p) // ok no EPC triggered
```

If you want to tighten this up you can use an extra type parameter to capture the actual parameter type passed in and force any excess properties to be of type `never`:

```
function createFunc<T>() {
    return <U extends T>(params: U & Record<Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>, never>): U => params /* do stuff here */;
}


const empty = createFunc<{}>();
empty({
    password: "",
    username: ""
}) // err

const login = createFunc<{ username: string, password: string }>();
const p = {
    password: "",
    password2: "",
    username: ""
}
login(p) // err
login({
    password: "",
    username: ""
}) // ok
```