# TypeScript discriminated union does not give error for non-existing fields

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Let's say I have this discriminated union type;

```js
interface SelectAction {
  type: typeof 'SELECT'
  payload: { values: string[] }
}

interface DeselectAction {
  type: typeof 'DESELECT'
  payload: {}
}

export type UnionAction =
  | SelectAction
  | DeselectAction
```

And I can use it like;

```js
export const deselect = (): UnionAction => ({
  type: 'DESELECT',
  payload: { test: 1, values: ['1'] },
})
```

TypeScript correctly shows that it does not expect any prop inside payload, but it also does not give any error if I pass them. I expect TS to give an error if I pass a prop that does not exist in that discrimination.

Is there way to use discriminated union in a more strict way so that it gives error in this situation?

TS will give error if I try to access those extra props but I want to avoid this since it can cause unexpected problems, for example if I use it like;

```js
switch (action.type) {
  case: 'DESELECT':
    return {
      ...state,
      ...action.payload // can contain unexpected props.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a bit more digging, I was able to came up with a solution.

I was expecting `{}` to be considered as an empty object but I learned that TS does not trigger excess property checks on `{}` https://stackoverflow.com/a/55512626/2703334. `Record<string, never>` was suggested for empty object check. With the combination of optional parameter I was able do;

```js
interface DeselectAction {
  type: typeof 'DESELECT'
  payload?: Record<string, never>
}

export const deselect = (): UnionAction => ({
  type: 'DESELECT',
})
```

In this way, I don't need to pass `payload` if I don't need it and TS gives an error if I try to pass unexpected values such as `payload: { test: 1 }`

But I still wonder when we don't pass `payload` to the interface why is it not considered as `payload: undefined`;

```js
interface DeselectAction {
  type: typeof 'DESELECT'
}

export const deselect = (): UnionAction => ({
  type: 'DESELECT',
  payload: { test: 1 }, // no error
})
```

Comment: I would do `payload?: never` instead, personally.  It just says "this property can never be set". Note that `payload` doesn't have to be an object.  You asked about the difference between `any` and `{}`.  The answer is that `{}` is any object, but `any` is any object and also string, number, null, undefined, etc.  Literally anything.

Answer (score 0):

from this code

```
interface DeselectAction {
  type: typeof 'DESELECT'
  payload: {}
}
```

you tell that the payload can have `any` type. What error do you need?

a short example:

```
let x = {};
x['test'] = 1234;
console.log(x);
```

will compile without problems.

To be more clear, I'll choose to set it as `undefined` and not to hide it:

```
interface DeselectAction {
  type: typeof 'DESELECT'
  payload: undefined
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `payload: any` and `payload: {}`is equivalent? Let me put the question in this way then; Even if I don't define `payload` in the interface with type 'DESELECT' I can still use payload in the object. In this case I expect discriminated union to consider `payload` as undefined and prevent any usage. But this only happens if I explicitly use `payload: undefined`.

Comment: {} may contains any key/value pairs

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now, I learned that TS does not trigger excess property checks on `{}`. But still I'm not sure if calling it equivalent to `any` is correct. But as I mentioned, even if I don't define `payload` in the interface I can still use any value for it. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64461431/2703334. I was avoiding `payload: undefined` because it was forcing me to pass `undefined` as value. Combination of empty object & optional parameters looks like the cleanest approach: `payload?: Record<string, never>`

Answer (score 0):

In this case typescript will infer the type of {} to be the {} type. This will allow you to add whatever properties you want to it but will allways throw a compile time error if you try and access any properties off of it. You could define an empty interface to take it's place

```
interface Empty {}
```

or you could make that property undefined if there is no payload.

Comment: Isn't "An empty interface is equivalent to `{}`"? This still behaves the same way as before. Defining it as undefined seems promising but it forces me to pass the `payload: undefined` to the object even when I don't need it. I wish passing no `payload` to that discrimination type would prevent me to give payload to the object.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I set up my example wrong you are correct, it will behave the same. You should be able to just not set it on the deselect type, so the interface will have no payload option and then you never need to pass it in or define it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I wish not defining `payload` would be considered as `undefined` value by TS. But if I don't define it in the interface, it allows me to use any value as `payload`. This was the solution I came up with: stackoverflow.com/a/64461431/2703334.

Answer (score 0):

why not do so

```
interface DeselectAction {
  type: typeof 'DESELECT'
  payload: { test: number } | null
}
```

OR Mark as not required

```
 payload?: { test: number }
```

This is how you define what it will contain

Comment: He give it an "any" type and ask why and how typescript don't treaty an object as an error?

Comment: @yoel That's the issue; I define the type with `payload: {}` or with no payload in the type. But I'm able to pass anything to the payload in the object.

Comment: @IsmailGül  What about this   ``payload: { test: number } | null``
OR Mark as not required like this ``payload?: { test: number }``