# TypeScript Wrong typechecking when remapping keys with `as` combined with generics

Tags: typescript, generics, types

With the new [index `as` syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as), I can filter out keys of a type as follows.

```
// Filter out all keys of `T` that do not exist in `U`
type IntersectKeys<T, U> = {
    [K in keyof T as K extends keyof U ? K : never]: T[K];
};

// e.g., IntersectKeys<{ foo: string; bar: number}, { foo: never }> === { foo: string }
```

However, when I use this type with generics, TypeScript seems to completely ignore typechecking.

**Is this a TypeScript bug?** **Is there a way around this?**

```
interface FooBar {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
}

function intersectFooBarKeys<U>(fb: FooBar, intersect: U): IntersectKeys<FooBar, U> {
    return false; // ---> !!Wrong implementation, but no type error!! <---
}

// Example usage
const fooBar: FooBar = {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 42,
};
const onlyFoo: { foo: string } = intersectKeys(fooBar, { foo: null });
// Based on its type, I would expect `onlyFoo` to be of the form `{ foo: string }`, but it is `false` instead!
```

Comment: Here's a far simpler example of what I believe is the same issue: https://tsplay.dev/m3PxbW. This is same issue because an unconstrained generic like `U` here, is basically just `unknown` while in that scope.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the same issue; even if you constrain `U` to `{[k: string]: any}`, the compiler still evaluates `IntersectKeys<FooBar, U>` to `{}`, as if `K extends keyof U` will always be false.  Seems like a TS bug to me, I'll search around for it

Comment: Eh, I'm not seeing an exact match; I *think* this is probably the same issue as [ms/TS#24560](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24560) and therefore a TS design limitation.  Someone could maybe (properly!) file an issue with [this code](https://tsplay.dev/NBy8zw) as a repro, but that person isn't me.

Comment: When you ask for "a way around this"?  Would something like `type IntersectKeys<T, U> = Pick<T, keyof T & keyof U>` be acceptable?  That behaves a bit better, I think.  Anyway, let me know if this and my previous comment would be good as an answer to this question (and I'd write it up).  Otherwise, could you let me know what I'm missing?

Comment: @jcalz That indeed seems like a workaround for this particular case. I would accept an answer with this workaround and a reference to the issue.

Comment: @jcalz I don't immediately see the connection with [ms/TS#24560](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24560) though. Could you also elaborate on that one?

Comment: I will do so when I get a chance; might not be for a while, unfortunately, I will be busy for the next day or so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug or design limitation in TypeScript.  The compiler is unable to reason much about higher order type manipulations like [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) over [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) types.  There are several GitHub issues around generic key remapping, like [ms/TS#45212](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45212)
and [ms/TS#48855](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48855) and [ms/TS#47447](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47447), but I don't see anything specific to this particular problem.  One might file a new issue with code like this as a reproduction:

```
type Foo<U> = {
  [K in "foo" | "bar" as Extract<K, keyof U>]: 1;
};

type X = Foo<{ foo: 0, baz: 0 }> // {foo: 1}
type Y = Foo<{ baz: 0, qux: 0 }> // {}
type Z = Foo<{ [k: string]: 0 }> // {foo: 1, bar: 1}

function generic<U extends { [k: string]: 0 }>() {
  type G = Foo<U> // {} <-- shouldn't this either be *deferred* or,
  // if anything, eagerly resolved to {foo: 1, bar: 1}? 
}
```

But I don't know what would come of that.

---

In general, when the compiler sees any sort of complicated type function involving generic type parameters, it can either decide to *defer* evaluation of it, thereby seeing it as an *opaque* type nothing is assignable to... or it can decide to *prematurely* evaluate it by substituting the generic type parameter with something related to it... thereby possibly resolving it to something incorrect.  It looks like the latter is what's happening here; no matter what `U` is, `K extends keyof U ? K : never` is being prematurely reduced to `never` inside the remapping clause, and thus you get `IntersectKeys<FooBar, U>` as `{}` independently of `U`.  And that's particularly unfortunate, since `{}` is special-cased and does not trigger excess property checks (see [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55512626/2887218)), and so `false` and just about anything except for `null` and `undefined` is assignable to it.  Oops.

Thus I'd say the issue is similar to that in [microsoft/TypeScript#24560](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24560).  We're trying to use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to filter a generic type related to `keyof` a generic type, and the compiler cannot figure out what that might be.  The operable [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24560#issuecomment-1067367324) in that issue says:

> Given an arbitrary constraint `T extends C`, there are very few things that can be readily determined about any possible instantiation of `T`-- you can't just use `C` as-is and get correct answers out of the other side. We have some logic in place when relating `T` as a subtype, but once you take a contravariant operation like `keyof T`, all bets are off.

---

Anyway, for your example code, my approach would be to stick to non-conditional non-remapped types where possible, since the compiler has slightly better reasoning abilities there (or at least defers them):

```
type IntersectKeys<T, U> = Pick<T, keyof T & keyof U>
```

This behaves as desired, or at least defers evaluation so that something like `false` isn't seen as assignable to it:

```
function intersectFooBarKeys<U>(fb: FooBar, intersect: U): IntersectKeys<FooBar, U> {
  return false; // error! Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'IntersectKeys<FooBar, U>'
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAVQHxQLxQN4CgpQDaA0lAJYB2UARAGYLVQA+NARgIYBOj7AzlAFEAHsE7sAxsETEANFADWEEHFpQ0AXQBcUAIwBuXAF8DuUJCgANTLASJsUenG0AGORwBeLqIfQB6XziO2jqGpuDQAJrW8Ej2Hi5yAI4ArkJePlD+OKFm0ABa0bb2hPLavKKUAOZaUM7efgHYQbpuXMGhuLTJFJJkcFSVEBQQnGTiKFAQIkMAJvzFpVDloxTV6agAFACUOPhQuVAA4oVIaJmNhlCIALTXSwAWcMkANjMUAOTA+-dk-BBkwHuIygrGgACoZhBaCNOBAZmCoHBOHIyKp2BQQICqnIIOxBpxniAoLDeHBngA3OH7OCBBDBVqcdoAfiguCMbI5WRgZGewGBTy+7GezwUSn4KigAAMACqS77sL4zGkUOBfKa-L6UKXISW4fwHACSFD5nF4EEkxDFiGlcjOWDwWSIpC1imUqmlUD4UFIUz5FDmordaigLNI2mGlM4NWlJHUBn8xjZhuNIzNFqtNrU6CwAAUxvJrXJXRKPQAyQMStBsrIQAB0lVrciNJrTwEtIF4dgcdKWFVWehBbSgFGSAFtQZxDHJ7M0I8CMhhFzhu05eytKt4ObhKCbaBJoDEAEJcXYEZrLKoGAgcRnDscTgwdLo9YB9Kg71Pm4BHrjtztoDZaFYbQf2RcgU1NL9tGQLZtGbT90w7RBQNtdA8AIWFgGSTgqD3Z4zQHGtOE4JEAEIoGlcIoHeVgEGeXEPnIfgVUFXheDISoKHYVh6OpfYqPeeDIMQzsUKzd52T1AJhHYUcwF45JeDxCBcHEfpyhXY9b1A6x0JXbR3kcd4ZD2G9tAAFgAJhMxM1IoDT+kJGJtBnHsL1WbxrA-YTvwQLS-0AvyuGnfS72FbwtnjAJjzNGZEXfYB+FyJsoAAdyeV5JiESBJClRyQBiOVgBpUFEVUQFoHoThRylVzV3cjdDElNxkk1TV+ElPCzTlShylxGZSLZIA)